# setuid trouble understanding

Tags: linux, permissions

I read about setuid and I did'nt understand the term in 100%.
As I undetstand: *setuid allow users to run an executable with the file system permissions of the executable's owner or group respectively and to change behaviour in directories.* (from Wikipedia).

But, I can't see a difference between:

**-rwsr--r--**  :::   you set to owner (rws is the owner) the setuid, so in other words you set to owner the owner permissions.
so there is no effect, right?

**-rwxr--r--**     :::    is equal to the previous example, beacuse as I said, already talk about the owner so it's does'nt matter to add the owner the owner permissions.

**THANKS FOR HELPS!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a executable with *setuid* bit enabled, it is run with the identity of the owner instead the user that is running the executable. Thus, if you has a executable which the owner is root and the *setuid* is enabled, the executable will run as root instead the user that is running the executable.

From man:

```
   setuid() sets the effective user ID of the calling process.  If
   the calling process is privileged (more precisely: if the process
   has the CAP_SETUID capability in its user namespace), the real
   UID and saved set-user-ID are also set.

   Under Linux, setuid() is implemented like the POSIX version with
   the _POSIX_SAVED_IDS feature.  This allows a set-user-ID (other
   than root) program to drop all of its user privileges, do some
   un-privileged work, and then reengage the original effective user
   ID in a secure manner.

   If the user is root or the program is set-user-ID-root, special
   care must be taken: setuid() checks the effective user ID of the
   caller and if it is the superuser, all process-related user ID's
   are set to uid.  After this has occurred, it is impossible for
   the program to regain root privileges.

   Thus, a set-user-ID-root program wishing to temporarily drop root
   privileges, assume the identity of an unprivileged user, and then
   regain root privileges afterward cannot use setuid().  You can
   accomplish this with seteuid(2).
```

You can verify this with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    int val;
    printf("The real user ID is %d\n", getuid());
    printf("The effective user ID is %d\n", geteuid());

    return 0;

}
```

Compile and setuid:

```
gcc uid.c -o uid
sudo chown root.root uid
ls -la uid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16712 Jul 10 11:59 uid
./uid                   
The real user ID is 1000
The effective user ID is 1000
sudo chmod 4755 uid     
ls -la uid         
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 16712 Jul 10 11:59 uid
./uid              
The real user ID is 1000
The effective user ID is 0
```

Comment: Thank you!
but still, there is nothing that is not clear to me: 

you said:
"it is run with the identity of the owner instead the user that is running the executable."
but, if I run as the owner already and not as the user setuid has no effect right?
so if I see the permissions: -rwsrwxr-x  1 owner group 883745 Jul  9 13:20 flag, this does not matter because I am already the owner, so it only changes from owner permissions to owner permissions? maybe I didn't understand well why need setuid...

Comment: Exactly, in that case it does not have any effect because the owner is the user who is running the executable.

Comment: Thanks!!! it will be nice if you can mark that my question was useful and then will to me more than 15 reputations and I will mark your answer as useful too because it is really useful!

Answer (score 1):

You already have a very complete answer from *sinkmanu*. But maybe an example to clarify why we need SetUID:

Check out the `passwd` command on your system. As a *regular user* you can change your password with this command. But to actually do this it has to change system files which are only accessible by *root*. Normally it would run as your user so it won't be able to access `/etc/shadow` for example, let alone write to it. But thanks to a SetUID bit the command will actually execute as it's owner which is *root*.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 33K Feb  7  2022 /usr/bin/passwd*
```

*Note*: If you have root access you can create your own SetUID programs. But be aware that this potentially poses a security risk. Security scans will often also scan a system for unknown programs with the SetUID turned on and alert the admins.